# How to retrieve older version of Procedure after database Restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

i created new procedure xyz in DB ABC. accidently someone restore that DB ABC with some other DB backup LMN. now i search for same procedure XYZ it doesn't exist. 
Is there some to get that SP xyz back  ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the database is in full recovery mode and you have a good backup and the transaction logs with the chain unbroken, it's possible for your DBA to restore the database to a point in time where your stored procedure existed and give you the code. 
2 important things I have learned the hard way. Backup your code and always backup your database before making major changes to it like a restore. I am hoping that someone did not fail to backup the existing database before performing a restore.

Comment: thanks @kubasnack for your  feedback. Is there any other way out?

Comment: What backups do you have and what recovery mode is the database in?

Comment: Maybe your database is stored on a LUN that has snapshots? If the restore overwrote the log file than you wont have much hope unless you can find a snapshot or backup of the storage location of the database or log at a time when your stored procedure existed.